# How to perform a gaussian blur using FFT?

Tags: image-processing, filtering

I am trying to implement a gaussian filter with matlab.Here is my implementation:
So far All I get as output is  a black image.
Any hints?

```
clear all;
close all;
I = double(imread('Put your path here'))/255;
I=rgb2gray(I);
sigma=1;
[M,N,s]=size(I);
f1=-fix(M/2):ceil(M/2)-1;
f2=-fix(N/2):ceil(N/2)-1;
[fx,fy]=meshgrid(f1,f2);
x=exp(-2*pi*pi*sigma*sigma*(fx/M.^2+fy/N.^2));
If=fft2(I);
If=fftshift(If);
If=If(:,:,1)*x;
If=ifftshift(If)
I=ifft2(If);
imshow(I)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working code,

```
clear all; close all; clc;

I = double(imread('Cameraman.tif'))/255; % Divide only if image value in [0-255] range
figure,imshow(I);title('Cameraman original')
%I=rgb2gray(I);  % NOTE: This is only for RGB images, commented otherwise
sigma=3;
[M,N,s]=size(I);
f1=-fix(M/2):ceil(M/2)-1;
f2=-fix(N/2):ceil(N/2)-1;
[fx,fy]=meshgrid(f1,f2);

X=exp(-2*pi*pi*sigma*sigma*((fx/M).^2+(fy/N).^2));
If=fft2(I);
If=fftshift(If);
If=If.*X;
If=ifftshift(If);
I=real(ifft2(If));
figure,imshow(I);title(['filtered image with \sigma =', num2str(sigma)])
```

Comment: Why do you do a point by point multiplication?Isn't convolution equivalent in the frequency domain a simple matrix multiplication?

Comment: It's a **sequence** multiplication not a **matrix** multiplication.

Comment: Can you please provide a link about that? I wish to read more about it.

Comment: The following [page](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/40579-frequency-domain-filtering-for-grayscale-images?focused=3778703&tab=function) is an example for MATLAB.

Comment: @damdam092 is the link ok?

Comment: Actually, it doesn't explain why we should use point wise multiplication instead of simple matrix multiplication.

Comment: Because **sequences** are multiplied point wise, like continuous function multiplication $f(x)g(x)$. There is no matrix/vector multiplication defined for them.